# Report Viewer Configuration Error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, webforms

I want to add some reports in my project and when I am going to show them that time I got following Error

> *The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers
>   section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers
>   section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.*

and my Web-Config file is looks like following: -

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
 </system.web>
```

I am not see any 'httpHandlers' portion here.. how can I overcome from this problem ?? After add 'httpHandlers' portion manualy still I get same error

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type =   "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this portion in my Web Config,finally I reach from this problem by following way : -

`<system.webServer>
    <!-- Add this to here.... -->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode"    verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>`